# Crypto Riddle for a bonus track

Tags: riddle, cipher

here is a crypto riddle a artist named Master Boot Record put on the page of his music.

> ```
> 087 104 101 110 032 116 104 101 032 077 111 111 110 032 119 105 108
> 108 032 115 104 101 100 032 110 111 032 108 105 103 104 116 013 010
> 087 105 116 104 032 116 104 101 032 069 113 117 105 110 111 120 032
> 099 108 111 115 101 032 098 121 013 010 073 110 032 116 104 101 032
> 100 097 114 107 032 097 032 115 112 101 108 108 119 097 114 101 032
> 114 105 115 101 013 010 082 105 100 105 110 103 032 111 110 032 097
> 032 108 105 103 104 116 110 105 110 103 032 115 116 114 105 107 101
> 013 010 013 010 077 097 100 101 032 111 102 032 099 105 114 099 117
> 105 116 032 098 111 097 114 100 115 032 097 110 100 032 098 121 116
> 101 115 013 010 070 111 114 103 101 100 032 116 111 032 099 114 111
> 115 115 032 111 117 114 032 115 112 097 099 101 032 097 110 100 032
> 116 105 109 101 013 010 084 104 114 117 032 116 104 101 032 115 116
> 111 114 109 032 109 121 032 115 111 117 108 032 119 105 108 108 032
> 103 117 105 100 101 013 010 084 111 032 116 104 101 032 112 097 116
> 104 032 102 111 114 032 103 108 111 114 121 032 097 110 100 032 109
> 105 103 104 116 013 010 013 010 078 111 119 032 106 117 115 116 032
> 116 097 107 101 032 115 111 109 101 032 111 102 032 121 111 117 114
> 032 116 105 109 101 013 010 087 104 105 108 101 032 119 101 032 115
> 104 097 114 101 032 116 104 105 115 032 114 105 116 117 097 108 032
> 110 105 103 104 116 013 010 084 104 101 114 101 039 115 032 097 032
> 115 101 099 114 101 116 032 103 105 102 116 032 116 104 097 116 032
> 104 105 100 101 115 013 010 066 117 116 032 119 111 110 039 116 032
> 099 111 109 101 032 119 105 116 104 111 117 116 032 097 032 102 105
> 103 104 116 013 010 013 010 070 105 114 115 116 032 121 111 117 032
> 110 101 101 100 032 116 111 032 103 101 116 032 116 104 101 032 114
> 104 121 109 101 013 010 087 104 101 110 032 104 101 114 101 032 099
> 111 109 101 115 032 116 104 101 032 100 097 114 107 101 115 116 032
> 110 105 103 104 116 013 010 084 104 101 110 032 121 111 117 032 116
> 097 107 101 032 116 104 101 032 102 105 114 115 116 032 056 032 098
> 121 116 101 115 013 010 067 111 117 110 116 032 116 104 101 032 112
> 105 110 115 032 097 110 100 032 110 111 114 109 097 108 105 122 101
> 013 010 013 010 079 110 099 101 032 121 111 117 032 103 111 116 032
> 116 104 101 032 110 117 109 098 101 114 115 032 114 105 103 104 116
> 013 010 074 117 115 116 032 098 101 119 097 114 101 032 116 104 101
> 032 111 100 100 115 032 097 114 101 032 108 105 101 115 013 010 076
> 105 110 101 032 116 104 101 109 032 105 110 032 097 032 114 111 119
> 032 097 110 100 032 119 114 105 116 101 013 010 084 104 097 116 032
> 119 105 108 108 032 112 117 116 032 116 104 101 032 099 111 100 101
> 032 105 110 032 115 105 103 104 116 013 010 013 010 078 111 119 032
> 100 111 110 039 116 032 115 116 114 101 115 115 032 097 110 100 032
> 116 097 107 101 032 121 111 117 114 032 116 105 109 101 013 010 083
> 111 109 101 116 105 109 101 115 032 119 111 114 100 115 032 099 097
> 110 032 116 114 105 099 107 032 121 111 117 114 032 109 105 110 100
> 013 010 070 111 114 032 105 110 032 065 083 067 073 073 032 099 111
> 100 101 032 121 111 117 039 108 108 032 102 105 110 100 013 010 084
> 104 101 032 115 111 108 117 116 105 111 110 032 116 111 032 116 104
> 101 115 101 032 114 104 121 109 101 115
> ```

Converted the ASCII numbers to text gave me:

> When the Moon will shed no light
>   With the Equinox close by
>   In the dark a spellware rise
>   Riding on a lightning strike
>
> Made of circuit boards and bytes
>   Forged to cross our space and time
>   Thru the storm my soul will guide
>   To the path for glory and might
>
> Now just take some of your time
>   While we share this ritual night
>   There's a secret gift that hides
>   But won't come without a fight
>
> First you need to get the rhyme
>   When here comes the darkest night
>   Then you take the first 8 bytes
>   Count the pins and normalize
>
> Once you got the numbers right
>   Just beware the odds are lies
>   Line them in a row and write
>   That will put the code in sight
>
> Now don't stress and take your time
>   Sometimes words can trick your mind
>   For in ASCII code you'll find
>   The solution to these rhymes

I'm actually really bad at riddle and need some help :/

[Here](https://masterbootrecord.bandcamp.com/album/interrupt-request) is the link to the website

Thank you.

Comment: The code that follows at that site may also be relevant. Its beginning [base64-decodes](https://www.base64decode.org/) to `My%U:ij(,;...`. The full code is: `6k3teSVVjbc6AxRpghGZ6Zxq2igsO6ZTaw+7tC9y7pSWObcZBydHsuuykMaOtr/xKSD8uA7lVkurGPkv7vK469AOkWkJBS2IuiMU8ploCziWvffkhyiSS2MRUEp9aRlH/9gdGuR5tAfMZEz4zHjqkt0eAfDe6y8yozwYWxIHSMzYHzFe37e5FaA/XXYXBQEz5/i9SKSNJsms002OrJCljVcHl4jCD7m1y3o7hBuaonGKpc9iY3+s3DIdqRJ8nP2Fa5cJx/IkDoiVvsyAVkq/Aue3pd6Fub4uzB5nambt0JVYAIO+GORdRwiLiuDIA4EvrKLZYv6z8CKkHdqjfC8KJmTRFwa+kwm2pLuUwaLIGSI=`

Comment: The thing about pins makes me wonder whether the [picture](https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a4244005369_10.jpg) is important...

Comment: The bit that tells you to solve the riddle for a bonus track also says "The code must overflow" (/irony?) in 1337

Comment: (By the way, thanks! I'm rather enjoying this music while working!)

Comment: HI,it seems that reddit is on the riddle too 
https://www.reddit.com/r/outrun/comments/71bvwe/master_boot_record_interrupt_request_new_album/